# How to get validationEngine.jquery.css with Nuget Package Manager?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validation-engine

I'm working with jTable :
http://www.jtable.org/Demo/UsingWithValidationEngine2
I need `validationEngine.jquery.css` 
I have the latest jquery, jquery-ui, and then install jQuery.Validation with:

```
Install-Package jQuery.Validation
```

But I don't see the folder `/validationEngine neither validationEngine.jquery.css

What I need to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ValidationEngine` used by jTable in your sample is different from `jQuery.Validation`.

The 1st one is made buy Cedric Dugas and available on GitHub and you can download all the elements you need (js file, css file, language files) here: https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine.

The 2nd one, "jQuery Validation", is a jQuery plugin made by Jörn Zaefferer (more info here: http://plugins.jquery.com/validation/), and is available directly as a package through NuGet when you are using Visual Studio.